# Java method not passing into main

Tags: java

so, I seem to be having a problem passing all three methods

machine Plays One

machine Plays Two

machine Plays Three

into the main function so that those if statements activate and begin counting/working. I understand that in order to print the methods I need to use

```
System.out.println(displayMachineOne());
```

but I'm just trying to get those if statements to work in the main so get the main counter working.

if the context is required: The objective is count how long it takes vickie to go broke playing predictable slots machines in sequence of 1-2-3-1-2-3-1 etc.

right now it just runs the loop 100 times (because 100 coins) and then she goes broke having never won anything.

I'm also pretty sure I need to return total quarters as well, but first I wanted to try getting the methods to pass properly.

any help is appreciated. (yes, I did try to google, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for)

```
public class WinningBig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalQuarters = 100;
        int totalPlays = 0;
        int machineOnePlays = 0;
        int machineTwoPlays = 0;
        int machineThreePlays = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            if(totalQuarters > 0) {
                totalQuarters = displayMachineOne(totalQuarters, machineOnePlays);
                machineOnePlays ++;
                totalPlays ++;
                totalQuarters--;

            }
            if(totalQuarters > 0) {
            totalQuarters = displayMachineTwo(totalQuarters, machineTwoPlays);
            machineTwoPlays++;
            totalPlays++;
            totalQuarters--;
            }
            if(totalQuarters > 0) {
                totalQuarters = displayMachineThree(totalQuarters, machineThreePlays);
                machineThreePlays++;
                totalPlays++;
                totalQuarters--;
                }else {
            System.out.println("Vickie lost all of her money! it took    " +
                    totalPlays + " plays for her to go broke");
            return;
        }
        }
    }

    public static int displayMachineOne(int totalQuarters,
                                           int machineOnePlays) {
         machineOnePlays++;

        if(machineOnePlays == 35) {

            totalQuarters += 25;
            machineOnePlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 25 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters) * .25);

        }
        return totalQuarters;

    }

    public static int displayMachineTwo(int totalQuarters,
                                           int machineTwoPlays) {
            machineTwoPlays++;

        if(machineTwoPlays == 100) {

            totalQuarters += 75;
            machineTwoPlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 75 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters) * .25);

        }
        return totalQuarters;
    }
    public static int displayMachineThree(int
            totalQuarters,int machineThreePlays) {

            machineThreePlays++;
        if(machineThreePlays == 8) {
            totalQuarters += 5;
            machineThreePlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 5 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters) * .25);

        }
        return totalQuarters;

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not storing the return value of these methods, try `winnings = displayMachineOne(winnings, totalQuarters, machineOnePlays);`

Comment: Or, since your return value for each is her total, you could do `totalQuarters = displayMachineOne(winnings, totalQuarters, machineOnePlays);`

Comment: Try remove machineNumPlays = 0 at the start of each function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class WinningBig {
    static int totalQuarters = 100;
    static int totalPlays = 0;
    static int machineOnePlays = 0;
    static int machineTwoPlays = 0;
    static int machineThreePlays = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            if (totalQuarters > 0) {
                displayMachineOne();
                machineOnePlays++;
                totalPlays++;
                totalQuarters--;

            }
            if (totalQuarters > 0) {
                displayMachineTwo();
                machineTwoPlays++;
                totalPlays++;
                totalQuarters--;
            }
            if (totalQuarters > 0) {
                displayMachineThree();
                machineThreePlays++;
                totalPlays++;
                totalQuarters--;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Vickie lost all of her money! it took    " +
                        totalPlays + " plays for her to go broke");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void displayMachineOne() {

        if (machineOnePlays == 35) {

            totalQuarters += 25;
            machineOnePlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 25 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters - 1) * .25);

        }

    }

    public static void displayMachineTwo() {


        if (machineTwoPlays == 100) {

            totalQuarters += 75;
            machineTwoPlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 75 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters - 1) * .25);

        }
    }

    public static void displayMachineThree() {


        if (machineThreePlays == 8) {
            totalQuarters += 5;
            machineThreePlays = 0;

            System.out.println("Vickie won on Machine One in the amount of 5 quarters, her total is now " + (totalQuarters - 1) * .25);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm counting the number of times she plays total, displaying that at the end (once she goes broke)

then each time she wins I'm displaying which machine she won on, how much she won, and the dollar amount. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok i have updated my code again, please try running this and see if it does what you are after.

Comment: It's telling me she played 105 times, but that can't be right. she should win on machine 1 at least once, and machine 3 a few times before she outright loses (I don't think she ever gets to win on machine 2). The solution says it's 155 times she gets to play, but I'm not really sure what's happening. Your code uses less variables than mine does though. Winnings was completely unnecessary?

Comment: Ahh yes I see because machineNumberWins is passed in its not changing the value in your main

Comment: I will show you how to fix this in just a minute if no one else has

Comment: I edited the main post, I'm not sure if that's what you mean by passing it in, but I got up to 130 before she goes broke with that.

Comment: Ok i have pulled out your variables and made them global, and then used them in your functions without passing them in. I believe this is working as intended now.

Comment: I usually try to avoid using global variables, but this works for me. How can I select this as the solution?

Comment: *I usually try to avoid using global variables* - they are not global variables, they are fields within your class

Comment: @Hakanoreaver Please avoid posting code only answers

Comment: @Scary Wombat I accidentally removed everything else when I pasted my new code in -.- I’ll add the text back when I’m back at a computer sorry.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ahh, yes, I see. Java doesn't support a true global variable like we had in C. Thanks! are static variables okay to use in java, or should I try to avoid them where possible?

Comment: Also, (quarters - 1) displays the total money amount incorrectly. So I took out the -1 (For any future readers) so, it's just totalQuarters *.25

Comment: Are you sure? You minus the quarter used to play at the end of your function. Shouldn’t the total be the winning + the total minus the quarter used for machine?

Comment: 79 quarters = 19.75 but it shows 79 quarters = 19.50 with the -1, I am assuming that `totalQuarters--` runs before the print statement displays.